# git show successively older versions of a file

Tags: git

Here is how to obtain the content of a file at a given commit:

```
git show <commmit>:path/to/checked/in/file
```

A good way to list all the revisions of a file is:

```
git log [-fancy -git -log -flags] path/to/checked/in/file
```

However this is a multi-step process. I must use the latter to list myself some commits which i then copypaste into the former incantation.

What I would love to know is if there is any syntax in git that will allow me to (similar to the semantics of `HEAD^`, `HEAD~6`) specify the older nth revisions of this file. e.g. `HEAD:path/to/file^^` for the 2nd last revision of this file.

Typical use case:

```
diff deployed/somewhere/file <(git show HEAD:path/to/file)
```

And I really really just want to modify this shell command with some `^` to keep scanning through the revisions of `file`.

This approach is actually still *kind of* usable. It's just that I may have to wade my way past `HEAD~35` before i encounter the first change in content in `file`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax for it—the graph operators work directly on the commit graph, while your `git log -- <path>` simply *selects* specific commits to *show*, while still looking at the larger graph.

What you can do is use `git rev-list`, which is `git log`'s sister command meant for scripting.  The same options that you would use for `git log` apply to `git rev-list`, but `git rev-list` produces *just* the commit hash IDs as an output stream.  Hence:

```
git rev-list HEAD -- path/to/file > /tmp/commit_hash_list
```

gets you the hash IDs of the commits that `git log` would show, one per line.  Read the lines, select the *n*-th line, and `git show <hash>:<path>` to extract the file.

(Replace `HEAD` with the branch name(s), or `--all` or other such option, that you would give to `git log` as appropriate.  For whatever reason, `git log` will default to using `HEAD`, while `git rev-list` requires a starting-point.)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I did expect that some amount of scripting would be necessary, but it does look like it is quite a small amount of scripting. Though, I did have to use `--all` with `rev-list`.